# Saber si una cadena contiene un texto en cierta posición

Tags: php

Buenas,

Quería saber si hay una forma sencilla de hacer lo siguiente. De un texto saco el número de veces que aparece el caracter `@`, y necesito comprobar si justo antes de esa arroba está el texto `rel="nofollow">`. Hay alguna forma de hacer esto sin tener que ir posición a posición, letra a letra?.

```
$times = substr_count($vista_previa_traducida, '@');
$array_menciones = array();

while ($times > 0) {

    $pos = strpos($extracto, '@');
    echo $pos;
    $espacio = $extracto{$pos-1}; //comprueba si >
    $comilla = $extracto{$pos-2}; //comprueba si "
    $uvedoble = $extracto{$pos-3}; //comprueba si w


    if ($espacio == ">" AND $comilla == "\"" AND $uvedoble == "w") {
        $extracto = substr($extracto, $pos+1);
        echo "esto es extracto: " . $extracto . "<br />";
        $pos_espacio = strpos($extracto, '<');
        $mencion = substr($extracto, 0,$pos_espacio);
        echo "Esto es mención: " . $mencion . "<br />";

        $array_menciones[count($array_menciones)] = $mencion;
    } else {
        $extracto = substr($extracto, $pos+1);
    }

    $times = $times-1;

}
```

Comment: Es posible que agregues tu codigo, para que nos muestres tu ejemplo y lo que llevas hecho?

Comment: creo que esto si es candidato a una regex..

Comment: @IvanBotero Lo acabo de agregar.

Comment: @gbianchi No sé a qué te refieres.

Answer (score 1):

**Podrias probar usando esto:**

1) Separamos todo el texto usando `explode()`.

2) Cada separacion de este texto se guarda en la variable `$cadena`.

3) Buscamos en la variable `$cadena`, si existe al menos un "@".

4) Si existe el arroba, buscamos si en esta cadena se encuentra el texto buscado `rel="nofollow">`

5) Buscamos las menciones *(De acuerdo a lo que indicas en los comentarios)*

6) Aumentamos el contador de "@" (arrobas)

```
<?php

$vista_previa_traducida = 'hola mundo @ esto es una prueba de @ texto rel="nofollow">@usuario</a> texto texto';
$array_menciones = array();
$contador = 0;

foreach(explode(" ", $vista_previa_traducida) as $cadena) {

    // Si encontramos el @
    if(substr_count($cadena, "@")){

        // Si dentro de la cadena se encuentra el texto rel="nofollow">
        if(substr_count($cadena, "rel=\"nofollow\">@")){

            $usuario = substr($cadena, strpos($cadena, "@") + 1 , strpos($cadena, "<") - strpos($cadena, "@") - 1);

            print "Usuario encontrado: $usuario\n";

            $array_menciones[] = $usuario;
        }

        // Contamos los @
        $contador++;
    }

}

print "Menciones: ";
var_dump($array_menciones);

print "Encontre $contador arrobas\n";

?>
```

#### Resultado

```
Usuario encontrado: usuario
Menciones: array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "usuario"
}
Encontre 3 arrobas
```

#### Nota

Para agregar un elemento a un `array()` **no es necesario hacer:**

`$array[count($array)] = $elemento;`

Basta con hacer:

`$array[] = $elemento;`

Automaticamente se agregara al final del arreglo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, tengo que marchar ahora lo pruebo luego, aunque croe que en el array estás introduciendo `"rel=\"nofollow\">@` siempre en vez del nombre de usuario. El código que tengo funciona pero quería saber si es posible hacerlo de forma más sencilla. Gracias por la puntualización de los arrays! no lo sabía.

Comment: @JetLagFox Podrias agregar a la pregunta, el contenido de la variable `$vista_previa_traducida`, por favor

Comment: @JetLagFox Ya he hecho unas correcciones respecto a lo que preguntas, de las menciones, al sacar el nombre del usuario que deberia estar despues del `@`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `strpos`:

```
$cadena = "<a href='' rel='nofollow'>"; // Simple ejemplo
$busqueda = "rel='nofollow'>";

if(strpos($cadena, $busqueda) !== false){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero entiendo que sólo busca si la cadena está dentro del string, no justo antes de la arroba.

Comment: @ahh, disculpa, no había leído bien, te puede servir una expresión regular, deja investigo un poco y veo si puedo ser más útil